# Does ngdbc.jar (2.4.67 or above) support JRE 11?

Tags: java, hana

Does ngdbc.jar (2.4.67 or above) supports JRE 11? (Manifest mentions usage of JAVA 6)

Answer (score 0):

The HANA 2.4.x JDBC driver supports JRE 6 **and later**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Note that ngdbc.jar is a [Multi-Release JAR file](https://openjdk.org/jeps/238) and as such supports multiple versions of Java. Learn more from this [developers.sap.com tutorial](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-jdbc.html#0738dfee-820b-4926-b9d9-8fe3005d2b47).